# Java detect url

Tags: java, http, url, hyperlink, href

I'm trying to make it in java so that if I type a message that contains a link it automaticly formats it with html so it can be clickable on a webpage :P

However, the code i have written only turns the first "link" in my message to a link, not the others.

Can someone help me with this? I'm out of ideas...

My Code

```
// URL and Image handling
    if (msg.contains("http://")) {
        // If url is an image, embed it
        if (msg.contains(".jpg") || msg.contains(".png") || msg.contains(".gif")) {
            msg = msg.replace(linkz(msg, true), "<img src='" + linkz(msg, true) + "' class='embedded-image' />");
        }
        // Send link as link in <a> tag
        msg = msg.replace(linkz(msg, true), "<a href='" + linkz(msg, true) + "' class='msg-link' target='_blank' title='" + linkz(msg, false) + "'>" + linkz(msg, false) + "</a>");
    }

// Check string for links and return the link
public static String linkz(String msg, boolean http) {
    String[] args = msg.split("http://");
    String[] arg = args[1].split(" ");
    if (http == true) {
        return "http://" + arg[0];
    }
    return arg[0];
}
```

Comment: Also, keep in mind not all URLs start with "http://" (unless you are the only one adding content and can guarantee you will always remember the http://). you can find some pretty nice regular expressions with some googling, though I've never found a perfect one.

Answer (score 1):

Use `replaceAll()` instead of `replace()`.

EDIT :

You can do it way simpler and cleaner with regex like this, instead of using splits :

```
msg.replaceAll("http://[^ ]+", "<a href=\"$0\">$0</a>");
```

Comment: Ye ty! But now if I post an image link and a regular link, the firest one changes the other... If I post a image link and then a link both turns to images....

My current code: http://pastebin.com/xsiPiuAM

Comment: getLinks() is in the class named CheckLinks.class and check() is in Handler.class

Comment: You can add somehting like '(png|jpg|etc...)' at the end of the regex to check if the link corresponds to a picture or not.

Answer (score 0):

For the additional images, you could use two replaces (with a negative look-behind for the second replace:

```
String msg = 
    "this is an example https://test.com/img.jpg " +
    "for http://www.test.com/ and yet more " +
    "http://test/test/1/2/3.img.gif test and more " +
    "https://www.test.com/index.html";

// replace images with img tag 
msg = msg.replaceAll(
    "https?://[^ ]+\\.(gif|jpg|png)", 
    "<img src=\"$0\" class=\"embedded-image\" />");

msg = msg.replaceAll("(?<!img src=\")https?://([^ ]+)", 
    "<a href=\"$0\" class=\"msg-link\" target=\"_blank\" title=\"$1\">$1</a>");

System.out.println(msg);
```

Gives you:

```
this is an example <img src="https://test.com/img.jpg" class="embedded-image" /> 
for <a href="http://www.test.com/" class="msg-link" target="_blank" 
title="www.test.com/">www.test.com/</a> and yet more 
<img src="http://test/test/1/2/3.img.gif" class="embedded-image" /> 
test and more <a href="https://www.test.com/index.html" class="msg-link" 
target="_blank" title="www.test.com/index.html">www.test.com/index.html</a>
```

Comment: Would it maybe be able to do this in javascript instead? :P Will it be the same code?

Comment: and if I use this. how would implement my youtube detetion code?

Comment: @enjikaka: Javascript does not implement negative lookbehind (the `(?<!img src=\")` bit, so it would be a bit different.  Though I'd say that's another question.